# Can I have different shipping/billig addresses for subscriptions?

Tags: stripe-payments

At the moment I am trying to figure out how to be able to set the address on a customer's invoice to something else than the customer's address.

This is how my service works:

A customer can add several payment methods (card, bank) and subscribe to certain products. However, a user might want to set different billing addresses for each subscription.

How would I do that?

From what I can tell at the moment I'd basically have to create a [`Customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) for *each* subscriptions. Although that's technically possible, this approach does not seem to be a good idea to me for several reasons.

The *easiest* thing would be if I could just store a different billing address to a [`Subscription`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create), or set a `address_id` to it which I would get from a *list* of addresses held by a `Customer` object. However, as it seems, this is not possible.

Or is it?

Any advice on how I could manage to do this would be great!

Comment: If they have different billing details, then they are technically a different customer for each subscription. IF they share the billing details, they can remain a single customer object. 

For each [token](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/object) (source) you can add address details, and they can function as your 'billing address'. If you issue your own invoices then you can populate the billing details based on this.

Comment: @Máté Well, I think I'll go for the multi-customer solution in this case. I'll have a customer for each subscription even though behind a set of subscriptions there might actually be just one user. Is that a way to go? Thanks for your input!